# Consul deployment issues in a three node cluster setup

Tags: consul

We are setting up a three node Cosul server. We are able to access only one of the server host but any other host is not accessible from the Consul UI.

Gives this error (No cluster Leader )

[image]

Here are the error logs that are present on the non working Consul Server node

```
2022-07-06T14:54:29.925Z [WARN]  agent: [core]grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {dc1-17.99.211.49:8300 lapp116.dc1 <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp <IP-1>:0-><Ip-2>:8300: operation was canceled". Reconnecting...
2022-07-06T14:54:41.537Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:55:05.054Z [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:55:06.052Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:55:28.927Z [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:55:31.513Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:56:02.307Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:56:03.070Z [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:56:26.165Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:56:35.031Z [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:56:55.459Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:57:07.616Z [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:57:27.686Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:57:35.128Z [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:57:58.915Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:58:03.708Z [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:58:22.158Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:58:29.168Z [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"
2022-07-06T14:58:50.469Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader
```

"

Need help !

thanks much.

Comment: How you configure it? Seem like you're wrongly configure the retry join config